# In Batman: Arkham Asylum, who is the prisoner in the room where Warden Sharpe is caged?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

In Batman: Arkham Asylum in the Cell Block room when you rescue Warden Sharpe (And receive the security hacker) there is a prisoner caged in a red straight jacket.

He can't be scanned, doesn't say anything (but makes a strange breathing sound) and seems to be more detailed than other thugs.

Who is this prisoner and does he represent anything?

Comment: Possibly a spoiler-y title?

Comment: I didn't know how else to describe it. Feel free to put a spoilers tag on it.

Comment: That prisoner is the creepiest thing in the entire game, with the sounds he makes. Gives me the chills.

Comment: Holy Cow, I finished that game twice and never came across this prisoner. :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[He is the winner](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/9734/contestwinner.jpg) of the "A life in Arkham" (or "Your face in Arkham", not sure) contest from Gamestop, where the first prize was to have your face in the game:

> Pre-order a copy of Batman: Arkham
>   Asylum in any GameStop store between
>   September 8th and October 15th, and
>   you could win a chance to be
>   immortalized inside the infamous
>   Arkham Asylum. One lucky winner will
>   have his or her face and likeness
>   created as an in-game character,
>   locked inside of Arkham Asylum for the
>   rest of their days.

So he's not a known villain, only a player integrated in the game. This explains also why he seems more detailled, he is made from actual photos (of the face, at least).

*I can't find correct sources for this, only a few posts on some forums, because the original GameStop page is not valid anymore.*

Comment: Awesome! I thought it might be something like that. Really cool :)

Comment: Heh, that's a very disturbing way to be remembered. Nice touch for the game! :)